# Ubuntu 14.04 64 bits - Only half of the RAM is recognized

Tags: 14.04, 64-bit, ram

I have 8 GBs of RAM (2 4 GBs memory sticks) in my computer. They are recognized by Windows 10, the "memtests" and the BIOS, but Ubuntu doesn't show more than 3696 MBs. I already tried several different Ubuntu versions but none have worked.

Some people told me to use the 32 bits version (which brings the PAE kernel), but I need the 64 bits version.

What can I do to use all the 8 GBs of RAM? Is it a bug? How can I fix it? Here are a few commands that may help you:

`uname -a`

```
Linux HolyHoundz001 4.2.0-27-generic #32-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 22 04:49:08 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

`free`

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       3785208    1125856    2659352      27552      31692     435708
-/+ buffers/cache:     658456    3126752
Swap:     15999996          0   15999996
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `free` terminal command.

Comment: What is the kernel version. Please add output of `uname -a`.

Comment: First of all: Ubuntu 32-bits gets basically all the same updates as 64-bits, and many people use it (including me). Also edit with the output of `uname -a`. And I'm going to edit it since it's a bit hard to understand. Y'know, "8 gigs" is not very specific.

Comment: 32bit does not get same updates u are wrong there ive used 32 and 64bit on alot diff pcs labtops they got alot bigg diff 32bit barly gets anything updateds like google chrome main browser is not being updated ever , whats hard to under stand i have 8 gigs ram hardware installed ubuntu 64bit can only see or use under 4 gigs no pae options in 64bit

Comment: If you are sure that all memory is seen in bios, then it is a kernel bug. I suggest reporting it to launchpad by running `ubuntu-bug linux`.

Comment: Yes, Ubuntu 32 bits gets **all** the updates. Google Chrome is not the main browser (it isn't even in the Ubuntu repositories). Firefox is the default Ubuntu web browser.

Comment: Please stop thinking that 32bit plus PAE gives you more RAM than 64bit. PAE (physical address extension) is just a virtual solution to have more memory addresses for the system, but still only about 4GB per process maximally. A 64bit system can address loads more memory without any extensions than 32bit. If you can use the memory with Windows and with Ubuntu 32bit, then it's a bug somewhere - just as @Pilot6 said.

Comment: Don't like Firefox much and don't play my flash games right Google's chrome only one that does.  And byte no clue what your talking about I no all about pae but I use 64bit if u looked and thought Linux detected hardware without BIOS weres that saport

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, a 32bit OS will not be able to handle memory addressing above 4 Gb.
I never had true faith in those PAE things: it needs specific hardware, compatible OS, compatible drivers, compatible applications...

If you are really using a 64bit Ubuntu (seems to be the case, according to your `uname -a`) and still have not all your RAM available, I strongly recommend you test each module separately (even if Windows shows it all, it may still be faulty)!

If this is a regular PC (ie: not a rented dedicated server), check the BIOS for any fancy RAM custom parameter (overclocking, or some weird a$$ *P!Mp My R4M* "feature" that may affect it's behavior): I've seen things so weird with so-called "gamer" motherboards...